# How can I make a vertical line between divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a vertical line between my div.
I want to my line to fit the whole height of the div, I couldn't get to do that.
I've tried border-right, and border-left of the next div.

Here is my my results

border-right
[image]

border-left of the next div
[image]

Can someone please show me the best way to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance.

---

## CODE

```
<style type="text/css">


 .panel {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  background-color: #4D8FCB;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;

}

.panel-heading {
  height: 114px;

}

.panel-body {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}


.sa-h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
}

.sa-h2{
  font-size: 28px;
}

.sa-h3{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sa-h4{
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sa-h5{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sa-h6{
  font-size: 10px;
}


.sa-right-items{
  float: left;
  /*line-height: 114px;*/
}

.sa-answer, .sa-score, .sa-review, .sa-report {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 22px;
}


</style>


<br><br>

<div class="row student-accordion ">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="row panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">

           <div class="col-xs-1 sa-section"  >

            <p><span class="sa-h5">SECTION</span>
              <br>
              <span id="sa-section-num" class="sa-h1">2.2</span>
              <br><span class="sa-h5">EXERCISE</span>
            </p>
          </div>


          <!-- Title -->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6" style="border-left: 2px solid white;" >
            <span class="sa-h3">Section Exercise 2.2</span><br>
            <span class="sa-h5">ALGEBRA 1</span> <br>
            <span class="sa-h4">02/09/2015</span>

          </div>

          <!-- Answers -->
          <div class="sa-right-items text-center">
           <span class="sa-answer">
            <span> <span class="sa-h2">11/25</span> <br> <span class="sa-h6">ITEMS ANSWERED <br> CORRECTLY</span> </span>
          </span>


          <!-- Score -->
          <span class="sa-score">
           <span> <span class="sa-h2">44%</span> <br> <span class="sa-h6">SCORE</span> </span>
         </span>


          <!-- Review -->
         <span class="sa-review">
          <img width="40px" src="/BIM/resources/images/icons-report/review_white.png"><br>
          <span> <span class="sa-h6">REVIEW</span> </span>
        </span>


        <!-- Report -->
        <span class="sa-report">
          <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#student-accordion-collapse"  class="pull-right">
            <img width="40px" src="/BIM/resources/images/icons-report/report_white.png"><br>
            <span> <span class="sa-h6">VIEW REPORT</span> </span>
          </span>
        </span>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div id="student-accordion-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">

     Contents

   </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/onms9kcu/2/)

Comment: those vertical lines are usually called borders.

Comment: @avrahamcool : didn't you see I try to use border ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the border style from `.col-xs-6 col-lg-6`, then:

```
.col-xs-1 sa-section {
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-top: -11px;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
```

Basically the border will show up within padding, so you just need to move the container up a bit (using a negative margin-top) and add some padding so the text shows up in the same place.

You will probably want to add an ID to the container and target it in CSS that way, instead of defining the styles of the class.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvzfj4rg/)

Comment: May I ask, how do u know `11` is the magic number ? How do you approach this kind of bug ? Did you use console ? How do you use console while in JSFiddle ?

Comment: I just went into the console (in Chrome, right-click -> Inspect Element), and played with the value of margin-top until I saw the border hit the edge of the container. Since your container has a defined height (as per your CSS) it is okay to use a pixel count in this way.

Comment: definitely the right way to do it. and border should be set on the left div as @wanovak did. not on the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/onms9kcu/3/

`border` inline style removed,  and added the below style.

```
.sa-section:after{
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
}
```